# Proper Method to Remove Broker from Kraft Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

I am curious what the proper method to remove a broker from a kraft cluster is?

I've adjusted replicas and partitions so that they aren't pointing to the to-be-removed node.
I've updated the broker.properties file of the to-be-removed node to exclude all controllers.
Then I wiped the __cluster_metadata-0 directory

This appears to have removed the node from the cluster, but it feels a little janky. Is there a better means of accomplishing this?